# Consulta Mongo por Fecha

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, mongod

**Resumen**

Tengo una API que basicamente cargar un json e inserta unos registros a un BD Mongo, mi pregunta para ustedes es; existe alguna consulta para mongo  que muestre que inserciones se hizo en x hora a x hora ?

(Se que se deberia poner un log en la API pero por ahora no lo vamos a poner, necesito es la consulta para mongo).

Si alguien tiene alguna idea se los agradeceré

Comment: Si no tienes actualmente ningun elemento en la coleccion que te indique ese elemento cuando se creó, quizás podrías basarte en el `_id`, pues el _id que genera mongo, una parte pertenece a la fecha de creación, quizás podrías basado en eso crear 2 ObjectIds y comparar un rango entre ellos... no estoy seguro que funcione, pero yo pensaría que es posible

Answer (score 0):

Para usar la marca de tiempo contenida en ObjectId y devolver documentos creados en una fecha determinada, puede usar [$where](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html#example) con una función.

```
db.tabla.find( { 
  $where: function() { 
    return this._id.getTimestamp() == new Date("2020-10-01") // YYYY-MM-DD
  } 
});
```

Comment: mira lo que me sale :/ 
Error:
Uncaught exception: TypeError: db.getCollection.find is not a function :
@(shell):1:1

Comment: Intenta con `db.getCollection("nombre de tu coleccion").find()`